# Search comma separated string using LIKE in mysql

Tags: mysql

I have a table with 3 columns something like below,

**expert table**

```
id        - 1589 
name      - Jhonny 
expert_in - 1,12,8 (Values similar like this)
```

The experts_in contains another table's foreign key

**experts_in table**

```
id        - 1
expert_in - painting
```

I want search experts who are expert in some jobs while searching for experts

```
SELECT * FROM `experts` WHERE expert_in LIKE 1%
```

The above query brings all experts with 11,12,13...etc. I want only exact word. I know LIKE will bring all. Is there any way to achieve this without altering table. 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you want specific values, then normalize your data; comma-separated lists of values make for inefficient searches, and kludgy workrounds. Or use FIND_IN_SET(), but it's nowhere near as efficient as a well normalized database

Comment: What you're doing is a bad practice. If there is manyToMany relation from expert table to expert_in table. You need to third table which hold foreign keys from both the table.

Comment: I understood this is bad practice. But my fate I should follow my senior's work!

Comment: If you can't control the database structure, then use [FIND_IN_SET()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set) rather than trying to use complex LIKE queries or REGEXP... The developers of MySQL introduced the FIND_IN_SET() function specifically to help people who are stuck with searching comma separated values in a column..... `SELECT * FROM \`experts\` WHERE FIND_IN_SET(1, \`expert_in\`) > 0`

Comment: Try this SELECT * FROM experts WHERE expert_in REGEXP '[[:<:]]1[[:>:]]';

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use `REGEXP`.
 Try this query:

```
SELECT * FROM experts 
    WHERE expert_in REGEXP '[[:<:]]1[[:>:]]';
```

**Output**: See Live Demo on [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/691d4/1)

**Note**: You can adjust searching string based on your requirement above REGEXP is searching exact word.

Comment: Thanks for the answer!

Answer (score 1):

if you can alter the data (not the table/schema) you should append and prepend another comma, so you can search with `where col like "%,123,%"`, this will always fit on an exact value. Otherwise you have to use regex with something like `,?123,?`

Comment: Can you please elaborate reg ex in my case?